# Capturing Time it Takes to Update the View in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to time in seconds how long it takes from when a user navigates to a page, to the time results are **displayed** on that page via an `$http` request

**EDIT:** I'm displaying this time to the user, similar to how Google displays theirs after a search

My code looks like this:

**ui-view**

```
<div>
  <h2>Awesome Surfers Directory</h2>  

  <!-- Display time it took to fetch and display all servers -->
  <small>Results returned in {{ executionTime }} seconds</small>

  <!-- Surfer List -->
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="surfer in surfers">
        {{ surfer.firstName + ' ' + surfer.lastName }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
.state({
  name: 'surfers',
  url: '/getSurfers',
  templateUrl: 'resources/components/surfers.html',
  controller: function($scope, $http){
    // Lets keep track of how long the fetch takes with a timer
    var t0 = performance.now(); 
    $http.get('fetchAllSurfers')
      .then(function(response){
        // Bind the results to scope - This could be several hundred results
        $scope.surfers = response.data;
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        // Oh no!
        console.warn('Woah dude, something like went totally wrong and stuff')
      })
      .finally(function(){
        // End the timer & bind to scope
        var t1 = performance.now();
        $scope.executionTime = (((t1 - t0) % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(1);
      })

    }
  });
```

The timer ends as soon as the request is complete, but well before the Surfers are actually displayed on the View/UI (which I assume is because Angular will take some time to update the DOM). I'd just like to know how to accurately capture this in my timer?

Any tips or help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not through Browser -> `Network` ?

Comment: @MaximShoustin I'm displaying this time to the user

Answer (score 1):

> The timer ends as soon as the request is complete, but well before the
>   Surfers are actually displayed on the View/UI (which I assume is
>   because Angular will take some time to update the DOM). I'd just like
>   to know how to accurately capture this in my timer?

Right, digest cycle takes some time to dispatch and render your stuff.

I would try to use [ngView -> $viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) event:

> Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.

```
 $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
   //view content is loaded
  });
```

---

You have several Chrome extensions Angular watchers. It will help you to understand if you got proper measurements:

- [angularjs-batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)
- [angular-watchers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Comment: I see the `$viewContentLoaded` is emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded, however I don't think this is capturing when the view is updated.  I placed the listener after my `get` request but it only fires once when the view is returned by not once `surfers` are displayed on the view

Comment: I appreciate the plugins! I will def check those out for home (unfortunately I can't install them on my company machine)

Comment: @KuraiBankusu please post more details about what info do you want to provide to client: full web page, specific element, ...

Comment: Updated the question - is this enough info? I'm utilizing UI Router to display a list of surfers returned from the http call. When the users navigate to this $state, it kicks off the request. Once complete, I want to bind the total time it took to fetch the results + bind them to the view